# using sed to find a string and replace it on a certain line + use the -i.bak

Tags: bash, sed

I want to replace spaces with underscores and brackets with nothing in the first line(note the 1 in here`sed -e '1s/ /_/g' head_test.csv` ) in a file.

This is the file I am working with:

```
$ head -n 1  head_test.csv
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description"
```

And this is how I achieve it using sed

```
$ sed -e '1s/ /_/g' head_test.csv |  sed -e '1s/(//g' | sed -e '1s/)//g' | head -n 1
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
```

but I having difficulty using the `-i.bak` option to overwrite the existing file. Can Anyone advise how i can do it using the -i option.

Comment: another way to overwrite but not havve the backups is `sed -e '1s/ /_/g' head_test_real.csv |  sed -e '1s/(//g' | sed -e '1s/)//g' > tmp && mv tmp head_test_real.csv
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to combine all 3 `sed` invocations into 1 like this and just add your `-i.bak` to create a backup file called `data.bak` before `sed` command executes, also there is no need to create a file just having the 1st line i.e no need for `head_test.csv` and the last `head` command at the end of the pipeline:

```
$ ls data*
data
$ cat data 
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description"
abcd
xyz
$ sed -i.bak -e '1s/\s/_/g' -e '1s/(//g' -e '1s/)//g' data
$ cat data
"Rec_Open_Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data_Volume_Bytes","Device_Manufacturer","Device_Model","Product_Description"
abcd
xyz
$ cat data.bak 
"Rec Open Date","MSISDN","IMEI","Data Volume (Bytes)","Device Manufacturer","Device Model","Product Description"
abcd
xyz
$
```

`-i` means in-place editing i.e `sed` performs all commands on the file data and persists all changes in the file effectively changing the file contents

`-i.bak` 1st creates a backup copy of the file: `filename.bak` and then makes changes to `filename`

Comment: tks, that looks like the job,  the `| head -n 1` was just for illustration.